# What are some good ways to earn cash?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

Getting a large sum of money in Assassin's Creed 3 is much different then previous version of the game. Gone are they days of buying every shop in town, and now we appear to have to actually do a little bit of labor for our money. What are some of the best ways of quickly earning large sums of cash. Are there some items that are cheap/easy to craft but sell for a boatload?

Comment: There might be a more efficient way, so I'm putting this as a comment. I found playing the pub games and betting the most I can is useful. Also, hunting for about 15 - 20 minutes, skinning, then trading everything I had will get me about 2000 - 3000 every time. This is all based on me playing though, I'm not super far.

Comment: @leety The games thing only works if you're actually *good* at them. Not that I'm bitter at getting schooled by the computer at checkers and X Men's Morris all the time or anything.

Comment: Get a job, you hippie!

Comment: I hear you @AnnaLear :) I figured I'd throw it in there for a comment though. I personally would feel bad saying "play this game" for an answer. It really relies on your skill to actually make money.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're like me and completely suck at the tavern games...

Hunting and selling pelts can be quite profitable, though a bit time-consuming. I like hunting wolves - they travel in packs and can be killed instantly with the hidden blade (unlike bears which take 3 hits) for a pelt in perfect condition. Beaver pelts are good as well. Beavers are slow and easy to track, and their pelts sell for boatloads.

I'm only on sequence 6 so far, and I'm also making decent cash from opening chests around the world, though I suspect this source will dry up shortly. :)

Haven't done much crafting yet since I need to gather more resources and artisans, but it doesn't seem like an efficient money-maker, since making the same item increases its cost for a while.

Sending your assassin recruits on missions is another source of income. It's not very quick, but it's pretty hands-off and passive.

Answer (score 6):

Go to the Homestead, buy as many bear pelts as you can. You can sell them on convoys and you''ll make a great profit. You should get more and more if you send multiple convoys at once.

Comment: Before you can get Bear, Beaver works really well too.  It has the added bonus of you being able to farm them en-masse by just going up and down the river, the place is lousy with them.

Comment: I feel sorry for beavers. They are so bad at not being killed. :(

Answer (score 4):

Buy bear pelt for £240 then sell it by naval convoy to saint Augustine for £1258 profit per pelt.The only downside is it takes 32 minutes but with 1 maxed out convoy you can sell 15 bear pelts for £19k

Answer (score 3):

A good idea for money making is to hunt beaver. They’re relatively easy, and a great spot to find a few is around the mine where Norris works. Just around the river, there’s raccoons, and beavers. Just use an arrow, or run up to them, they aren’t very fast. The hides sell for quite a few pounds if you market them through the use of caravans. Otherwise, they’re only 160 pounds. Make sure to sell them to the FIRST general store you unlock, the one from the tutorial. The second one won’t pay nearly as much.

Answer (score 2):

Sell ale and upgrade your homestead as early as possible. Officer's swords 1220, cannon 1400, fine clothing 1230, fine shoes 1002 pelts make good filler whilst stockpiling parts to craft large items. Try to rotate artisans wood buttons, blades, linsywools, send pelts. Next trip back make weapon handles, then make fine clothing and officers swords. Also with 4 major artisans you can rotate stock pretty effectively.

Answer (score 2):

Elk and bear pelt farming for trading.  There are tricks to hunting bears.  Hit them from an air attack, or jump right before they attack you.  Then you can 1shot them.  Here's a vid of bear and elk pelt farming that can be done over and over:

[Assassin's Creed III bear and elk pelt farming](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q4MKDY2TPSg)

Answer (score 0):

Also, a good way to make money is by finding chests. Some may have 10k gold and others 7500 or 1250. You can buy chest maps at any general store for 2000 or 2500 gold.

Answer (score 0):

Do one liberation mission that grants the ability where your friends become guards and take you as a prisoner. (This should be done before Sequence 7, or otherwise before you do any liberation missions.) Go into a fort under British control that hasn't been freed and use the aforementioned ability without entering alerting anyone. Open the chest, leave, and enter again.

Find the fort with the most chest cash to make a ton of money. This makes about 10K every 10 minutes if you find the right fort.

Comment: Hello, welcome to gaming.stackexchange.com, and thank you for your answer. However, as it stands your answer is both difficult to read and hard to make sense of. Please consider editing it to clarify the grammar. Unfortunately I'm not familiar enough with the game to make an accurate guess at what you mean or I'd do it for you.